# userdata for openstack image which is generated using packer

Tags: image, openstack, packer, user-data

I am creating images for openstack using packer, but we also have requirement that these images should execute few commands (one time, post-boot) when they are deployed as VMs by customers. Openstack provides `userdata` option in both GUI & CLI, but how can we include these in the image itself?

I looked at `user_data` option in packer openstack builder but it seems getting executed only during image creation, not while deploying VMs using the image

Comment: user_data is consumed by cloud-init during instance creation. So the image requires a configuration and enabled cloud-init services.

Comment: @eblock do you have any examples of it is done?

Comment: https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html

Comment: @eblock but how do I pass this `user_data` during packer image creation? the `user_data` parameter/option in openstack packer builder seems executing the `user_data` part during the image creation, not when VM is created using the packer output image. my requirement is, user_data commands/steps should not be executed during image creation, but execute them when a user uses that image and boot the VM for the first time.

Comment: Your image should only have the cloud-init services enabled and a valid `cloud.cfg`, the rest is done by openstack when you launch an instance. You can pass a user-data file to the instance via CLI or dashboard and it is then executed during instance boot.

Comment: @eblock thanks for the reply, but our requirement is not to pass anything during instance boot, instead these steps some how should be imbedded inside image and get executed during first boot.

Comment: btw, cloud-init service is enabled and has valid cloud.cfg file

Comment: I'm not familiar with packer, I only use user-data with cloud-init when I want to inject custom data into the instance. The injection happens via neutron metadata service. You write "our requirement is not to pass anything during instance boot [...]  and get executed during first boot", this is a little contradiction in my opinion. Everything you pass into the image will be the same for all instances, if you want to customize things you use cloud-init. I may be wrong, but as I said, I don't know how packer works.